# How to make SQL query to get the frequency of applications?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table:

```
***application***

application_id     application_applicantid
  2                     4
  3                     14
  5                     18
  6                     18
  8                     18
  1                     10
  4                     10
  7                     18
```

I want to produce query output as follows:

```
  0 application - total
1-5 application -total
more than 5 applications - total
```

I want to get the result of applications categorized by 3 category frequencies (0 application, 1-5 applications, >5 applications). The applications which have the same application_applicantid means applying for x-times applications.

How can I make SQL query for that?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images. (Or, even worse, links to images.)

Comment: okay..i'll edit my question.thank you

Comment: i already edit my question, can anyone help me?

Comment: Your schema is still not clear and you haven't mentioned your dbms what is 1-5 is it application_id?

Comment: `0 application - total` what's that supposed to mean? Your question is absolutely unclear.

Comment: i'm using mysql. i want to get the result of applications categorized by 3 categories frequency(0 application, 1-5 applications, >5 applications). the applications which has the same application_applicantid means applying for x-times applications.